# ssscanf unexpected behavior

Tags: c, sockets, io, scanf

When I use sscanf on url http://www.website.com:30081/text.txt, like this:

```
int parse_url(char *url, requesthdrs *hdrs, char 
              *uri, char *domain_name) {    

   int request_port;                                                                 
   int host_hdr_len;                                                                 
   char temp[MAXLINE];                                                               
   size_t uri_len = 1;                                                               

   /* case 1: request_port specified */                                              
   /* format: http://domain_name:request_port/... */  

   if(sscanf(url, "http://%s:%d%s", domain_name, 
             &request_port, uri) == 3) {         
     fprintf(stderr, "case1\n");                                                     
     host_hdr_len = build_hosthdr(hdrs->host, 
                                domain_name, request_port);            
   }
```

The program fails to enter case 1, why is that the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `%s` reads until the first white space, or end of string.  That isn't what you want or need.  Use `%[^:]` (a scan set that matches anything except a colon) 
instead.

Beware of buffer overflows.  You don't know how big the strings can be.